# Swift iOS: fatal error when dismissing alert controller while keyboard is up

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uialertview, uialertcontroller

So, I’ve got a view controller with a number of text fields on it. The first two text fields need text entered into them before submitting. I check the first two text fields and display an alert controller in case they’re empty.

```
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message:
                "Please enter some text.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This works fine, as long as the keyboard is dismissed before trying to submit the form. If the keyboard is still showing however, the app crashes with fatal 'error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'

What is happening here?

Comment: i think the crash does not have anything to do with the code you provided. can you maybe show some more code and/or the crash log?

Answer (score 1):

Just solved this myself by adding `view.endEditing(true)` before displaying the alert controller. Would still like to know why it was crashing in the first place.

Comment: It doesn't crash. It dismisses the keyboard automatically while the alert is shown.
Post more information about the crash please. (line, etc. )